# Property 'content' does not exist on type 'HTMLElement' in Typescript

Tags: javascript, typescript

I get error when I try to get the content of meta tag:

```
document.getElementById('mymetatag').content
```

in Javascript is works, but typescript say that

```
Property 'content' does not exist on type 'HTMLElement'
```

So how to extend the HTMLElement type interface to support content property?

Comment: Can you try like ```(<HTMLInputElement>document.getElementById("mymetatag")).content``` ?? This works only if the element is input..

Comment: `Property 'content' does not exist on type 'HTMLInputElement'`. also I prefer to extend the interface

Comment: Can you also post the html code of the element where the id ```mymetatag``` is mentioned?

Answer (score 11, accepted):

TypeScript doesn't know what kind of element has this specific ID. It cannot trust the element even exists to begin with!

You need to introduce another check in order to validate your assumption:

```
const element: HTMLElement | null = document.getElementById('mymetatag');

if (element instanceof HTMLMetaElement) {
  element.content;
}
```

**Update**

You can also use assertion signatures.

```
function assert(condition: boolean, message: string): asserts condition {
  if (!condition) {
    throw new Error(message);
  }
}
```

Then your solution becomes:

```
const element: HTMLElement | null = document.getElementById('mymetatag');

assert(element instanceof HTMLMetaElement, "A <meta> element of id 'mymetatag' needs to exist in the DOM.");

element.content; // string
```

Answer (score 3):

Also, for `<template id="source">`, you can use HTMLTemplateElement

```
const source = document.querySelector('#source') as HTMLTemplateElement;
const sourceClone = source.content.cloneNode(true) as HTMLElement;
```

Answer (score 1):

`document.getElementById()` returns an `HTMLElement`. 
But you know that your result is a meta tag, which is a type of `HTMLMetaElement`.
Looking at the [docs](https://microsoft.github.io/PowerBI-JavaScript/interfaces/_node_modules_typedoc_node_modules_typescript_lib_lib_dom_d_.htmlelement.html) you can see that `HTMLElement` is the ancestor of `HTMLMetaElement` so you should downcast your element to this type. You can do this with two different syntaxes:

```
const metaElement = document.getElementById("mymetatag") as HTMLMetaElement;
// Or the second version:
//const metaElement = <HTMLMetaElement>document.getElementById("mymetatag");
const metaContent = metaElement.content;
```

See more about type assertions [here](https://www.typescriptlang.org/docs/handbook/basic-types.html#type-assertions).

Answer (score 0):

Try following:

```
(<HTMLMetaElement> document.getElementById("mymetatag")).content;
```

Comment: You shouldn't use custom types when there's an "official" one. Search for HTMLMetaElement .